# Is the following email correct?

Tags: writing, email

Thank you for your responce!!!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This site is organized around helping people with common problems that can have single, authoritative answers; as such, requests for proofreading are explicitly off-topic. We would be happy to assist, however, if you identify a specific question of grammar or usage that confuses you. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Try www.italki.com if you sign up for an account (which is free), you can can ask native speakers for free proofreading

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very well done. Corrections: (1) to study law at the undergraduate level (add *the*). (2) Either *specific* or *particular* is fine. (3) I suggest changing "are these courses enough to make me eligible" to "do these courses suffice to make me eligible." But there is nothing wrong with the way you have written this. (4) Change "if the results of midterm exams will be released only in late January" to "if the results of midterm exams are released only in late January" OR to "given that the results of midterm exams will be released only in late January." (5) In the final line, "Thank you for your time, I look forward to your reply," make this into two sentences by changing the comma after "time" to a period.